# Error creating new migration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We've got an odd issue that I'm hoping someone can explain. We are using EF migrations (4.3.1) and when we run an `update-database` and it returns that there are no pending migrations however if we then make some changes and run an `add-migration` it says it can't create it as there *The model backing the 'XXXDatabaseContext' context has changed since the database was created*.

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
PM> add-migration Foo
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'EntityFrameworkDatabaseContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
```

However setting the initializer to null sorts it

```
static MyDbContext() {
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
}
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Did you edit the exception message? Is `EntityFrameworkDatabaseContext` actually the same as `MyDbContext`?

Comment: Yes @DavidG I did, the stack trace is correct